# Puedo añadir archivos css desde el backend al fornted

Tags: wordpress

Hola buenas tengo una windget en el dashboard de wordpress con un desplegable
dependiendo de la opcion del desplegable quiero que carge una hoja de estilos en el frontend el codigo es el siguiente

```
function custom_dashboard_widget_coach() {
//get saved data
if ( !$widget_options = get_option( 'my_dashboard_widget_options' ) )
    $widget_options = array();
    $saved_team = isset($widget_options['team'])? $widget_options['team'] : '';
    if ($widget_options['team'] == "si")
    {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
    }
    else{
        wp_enqueue_style( 'show-exitos', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/show-exitos.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    }
    echo "
    <p><strong>Casos de Exitos</strong></p>
    <div class='team_class_wrap'>
        <label>Ocultos {$saved_team}</label>
    </div>
    ";
}
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'hidden-exitos', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/hidden-exitos.css', false ); 
}
```

El widget funciona correctamente y guardo la opcion del despelgable lo que ocurre es que no me carga la hoja de estilos con el wp_enqueue_style

Agradeceria cualquier consejo o guia

Gracias

Comment: Eso que quieres hacer se hace con javascript desde el mismo Frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion sin necesidad de usar javascript solo php
la solucion era poner el if dentro del archivo enqueue.php de la caberecera quedando asi:

```
if ( !$widget_options = get_option( 'my_dashboard_widget_options' ) )
$widget_options = array();
$saved_team = isset($widget_options['team'])? $widget_options['team'] : '';
$file =  get_template_directory_uri().'/css/hidden-exitos.css';
if ($widget_options['team'] == "si")
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hidden-exitos',$file, false );
}
else{
    wp_dequeue_style( 'hidden-exitos',$file, false );
}
```